# How to map getFrameNumber of CameraResult for Image receive from ImageReader Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2, image-reader

I need `getFrameNumber` for Image object received from `ImageReader` for my camera2.

Currently, I received different timestamp for the following code so due to that, I am not able to map `getFrameNumber` of `CameraResult` callback.

```
 CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListenerLeft = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                Log.d(TAG, "#### Camera Preview: FrameNumber:[" + result.getFrameNumber()+"] TimeStamp:[" + result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP) / 1000000 + "] Expo:[" +result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)+ "] FrameDuration:[" + result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION) + "]");

        }
    };
```

Now at ImageReader Callback:-

```
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mImgLeftCameraListener=new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {

            try{
                Image mImage=imageReader.acquireNextImage();
                long mTimeStap=mImage.getTimestamp()/1000000;              
                mImage.close();
            }catch (Exception exc){

                exc.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

Now the issue is Image reader `mTimeStap` does not match with `result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP) / 1000000` value, So i am not able to map getFrameNumber.

NOTE: My android is 7.1.1 custom OS build for Qualcomm 820.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps are the only way to match these; by design of the API, they should match. What kinds of differences are you seeing in the timestamp values?

Edit: And to add, there's no way to get a frame number from the image reader; that value is not passed to the ImageReader at all.